# Back filling an AirFlow DAG for additional historic dates

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have an AirFlow DAG which copies data from my Google BigQuery database into another dataset, and it's working fine.

I want to copy all the existing tables, but I accidentally set my start date one year too late, resulting in a year's worth of data not being present in my new dataset. To try and fix this I set the start date back another year and manually triggered the DAG, however it is not back filling the tables as expected - instead the DAG is stuck on 'running'.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 9, 27),
    'end_date': datetime(2017, 9, 27),
    'email': ['xxx@xxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
```

What is the correct process to amend a start date and collect data that was not pciked up with the first start date?

Answer (score 2):

So whenever we've had to the modify `start_date` we just rename the dag to avoid funky scheduler issues as we've found it to be the easiest and least destructive approach.

I know we shouldn't just link to other pages, but the approach of renaming the `dag_id` is also mentioned in the Airflow Confluence in the 3rd to last point, however it specifically mentions using this approach when changing *both* the `start_date` and the `interval` given that the scheduler uses both of these pieces of information to figure out when to do a DagRun:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls

Again though, we just go with the rename approach and it's worked for us.